# Trying to pass variable from JavaScript to PHP using Ajax but got error " Undefined array key"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have had this error for multiple days now, I have tried searching this error up but whenever I search this error up it gives a different reason for the error and when I try to add what other sites say it doesn't work which is why I am asking here as I don't see what else I can do.

I am trying to pass a variable from JavaScript to PHP but it is not working and I have no idea why.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> </script>
</head>

<script>
var variable = "hello";
console.log(variable);
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{pass : variable},
        success: function() { 
              alert("Success"); 
        } 
    });

</script>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
$variable = $_POST['pass'];
echo($variable);
```

Everything seems to work perfectly. It writes the variable to the console, it comes up with the alert saying success. However I get an error message saying: 'Undefined array key "pass"'

What is causing this? Thank you?

**Edit:** People have told me to use isset, I have added that it removed the error however it still does not echo the PHP variable, meaning it is still not been passed to PHP, I am still trying to find how to fix this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243188/discussion-on-question-by-puckloe-trying-to-pass-variable-from-javascript-to-php).

Answer (score 0):

Your front end code looks OK, but I don't know your target PHP environement, but maybe your environnement doesn't accept [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData).

By default, jQuery send ajax POST data as [formData](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Try to send data as JSON

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({pass : variable}),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){alert(data);},
});
```

And then you will probably have to adapt your php code:

```php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Converts it into a PHP array
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$variable = $data['pass'];
echo($variable);
```

Comment: I tried doing this and now it gives me a different error it now says: "Trying to access array offset on value of type null "

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the payload of your request in the network tab of the browser inspector. Or right click on your request and "copy as fetch" and then juste past result here ?

Comment: Sorry how can I see the payload of the request. I am using a browser and have pressed inspect what do I do from there?

Comment: Go to "network tab" then you will see all the requests. Just right click on the requests and "copy as fetch"

Comment: And please also copy response

Comment: there is no need to change datatype, @puckloe your code works fine, you just don't have clear understanding of it yet. PHP warning is also correct, its telling you not to miss little details like here you are trying to using `$_POST['pass']` before you have sent it via ajax, so added `isset` to check if it is sent, and php `echo` wouldn't print anything on page it will send the response to ajax and you have to receive it in success function so you can use it as you want. also add error function so you would know ajax call was not successful.

Comment: ok this is what it gives:

fetch("http://localhost/test/ajax.php", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"99\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
  },

Comment: "referrer": "http://localhost/test/ajax.php",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": "pass=hello",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use the developer tools in chrome browser that will help you to find if data is properly sent to php file.
Also you can try $_REQUEST instead of post just to check what data is coming in REQUEST as it works for GET & POST both. If it still does not help you.

Also can you please use

```
data: {'pass':variable}
```

instead of

```
data: {pass:variable}
```

let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Trying to use data: {'pass':variable} does not work

Sorry what is the developers tool in chrome and how can I use it?

When I use REQUEST it gives the same output.

Comment: that you can check by right click on page and then from menu item select Inspect or you can use shortcut if you are already aware of that.
then go to network tab and then hit request by ajax.
then you can view in payload what data you sent by ajax.

Comment: Request Payload should send some json data key pair value like {"pass": variable}
You should be able to see there.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error in your ajax.php file which you Post the data to it, I say it's normal because when you open that file (ajax.php) it's like that there is no $_POST['pass'] because you just opened that file without running JS to send data.
If you want to receive data that you send you can do this:

Your JS code I call this file index:

```
var variable = "hello";
$.ajax
({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data:{pass : variable},
    success: function(res) { 
          alert(res); 
    } 
});
```

The PHP file:

```
$variable = $_POST['pass'];
echo($variable);
```

Then if You open up that index file, after running the JS code it'll send that post data to your PHP file and your PHP file will echo that, then the value will store in that `res` variable which when every thing went fine, you can see the alert of that `res` in the page (index file).

Notice that as I said you can't open up the PHP file lonely because it doesn't receive a post data on its own, it is normal for undefined to return.

Answer (score 0):

Re: @puckloe your code is working, php `echo` wouldn't be printed with ajax(***correction `echo` is working but wouldn't show on page if you don't print it with JS too***), you have to catch the response in ajax success function ( like `success: function(response)` ) and print or alert the response --> `success: function(response) { alert("hi look this is echo from php"+response) }`

you ajax code should look like

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:{pass : variable},
        success: function(response) { 
              alert("hi look this is echo from php" + response); 
        } 
    });
```